# winspool.Drv ClosePrinter doesn't actually print, but I can see it in the queue c#

Tags: c#, printing, unmanaged

My code is

```cs
// Open the printer.
if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName, out hPrinter, defaults))
{
    // Start a document.
    if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
    {
        // Start a page.
        if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
        {
            // Write your bytes.
            bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
            EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
    }
    ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
}
// If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
// about why not.
if (bSuccess == false)
{
    dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    throw new Win32Exception(dwError);
}
```

The result is that I can see the spool in printer queue
[image]
but it doesn't actually print....the printer does nothing....

I have windows 10, my printer is attached to my personal pc and I am working at other pc using VPN connection.

and this way I read and data/pointer

```cs
public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
{
    // Open the file.
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
    // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
    bool bSuccess = false;
    // Your unmanaged pointer.
    IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
    
    int nLength;
    nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
    // Read the contents of the file into the array.
    bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
    // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
    pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
    // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
    // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
    bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
    // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
    return bSuccess;
}
```

Comment: the `N/A` pages (and the 181 bytes size) _strongly_ suggest that there's something wrong with the data you're trying to print

Comment: any dirrection on how i can find the wrong?

Comment: post updated, plz check

Comment: you do realize that .NET Framework has a wonderful Printer API and there is absolutely no reason to use the Win32 API, correct?

Comment: i didnt find something free that work. can you provide me some open source?